# $0 sometimes not set while running in Linux. What could be the reason?

Tags: perl

I am running a Perl program in which I use the variable `$0` to get the script name. While it works correctly most of the time, it is not giving any values for few scripts. The scripts are the same as any other scripts and have a proper name to it.

Can someone help me identify the issue? If you want more details, please let me know.

Comment: it should always be set. Are you using it directly, or passing it around through other code which might be introducting issues?

Comment: Are you running the scripts as `$ ./myscript.pl`, `$ perl myscript.pl`, `$ perl -e 'require "myscript.pl"'` or `$ cat myscript.pl | perl`? There cannot be a sensible value for `$0` with the latter two.

Comment: test it with `print $0.":".@ARGV."\n";`

Comment: "The scripts are the same as any other scripts and have a proper name to it." I doubt it. If `$0` is getting unset or something, the script is probably doing it. I don't know of any reason it would be empty. It is legal to assign a value to `$0`.

Comment: @nirmal: post examples of your code demonstrating the issue...

Comment: Hi Pavel, The code is a very basic assign statement using $0. Check this line=> $script_name_to_register = $0; This particular line runs in a loop where other API calls also happen before/after this line. While $0 initially has values, some instances inside the loop makes it NULL.

Answer (score 1):

It's not always set to what you might think it would be:

```
perl -e 'print $0'
-e
```

Please post actual code showing a case that doesn't do what you expect it to.  If you print it from inside an eval, for example, what do you expect it to print?

Comment: Hi Stark, Thanks for your time on this. The code is a very basic assign statement using $0. Check this line=> $script_name_to_register = $0; This particular line runs inside a loop where other API calls also happen before/after this line. While $0 initially has values, some instances inside the loop makes it NULL. Only thing I can confirm is that none of the APIs I use is deliberately changing it.